# Cannot Retrieve Data from Excel File Created using Aspose.Cells

Tags: excel, excel-2007, aspose, aspose-cells

I create an Excel file (.xlsx) using the Aspose.Cells library. But I'm not able to read the data (**retrieve rows**) using OleDb commands after that, **until I open the file and save it manually**. I'm running something as simple as this one:

```
new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", conn); // etc...
```

Saving the file increases the size of the file as well. Please note that this happens **only with the .xlsx format**, for the old .xls everything works fine. I even tried the demo code that they have on their website, but the result is the same. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to set the **ExportCellName** name property to **true** before saving to xlsx/xlsm format.

Please see the following sample.

```
//Create your workbook
Workbook workbook = new Workbook(filePath);

//Do your processing

//Save your workbook with export cell as true
OoxmlSaveOptions opts = new OoxmlSaveOptions();
opts.ExportCellName = true;
workbook.Save("output.xlsx", opts);
```

*Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using the version 4.8.1.0 and I cannot find the OoxmlSaveOptions class in the API. There's only the SaveOptions class which doesn't have the property described above.

Comment: Please give a try to latest version which you can download from Aspose because it might be a bug in the older version.